# Openmediavault assemble raid6 with mdadm

Tags: debian, raid, storage, software-raid, mdadm

I have a raid 6 with 1 hot spare. I the initial config was with 5 6TB drives then I added 2 more 6TB drives with the openmediavault web interface. Everything was fine after that. But the last time when I added an other 6 TB drive, initially there were no problem but after 4-5 Hours of reshaping the drive stopped working. And now the array is inactive and I can't reactive the array.

I haven't partitioned my drive.
And also my web interface is not working.

I have tried.

```
$ mdadm --stop /dev/md127

# Then tried to remove the faulty drive by.
$ mdadm --manage /dev/md127 --fail /dev/sde
$ mdadm --manage /dev/md127 --remove /dev/sde

# And then I then I tried to reassemble the array with.\
$ mdadm --assemble --scan # and it gives this output
mdadm: /dev/md/RD6 assembled from 3 drives and 1 spare - not enough to start the array.
```

My `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`

```
ARRAY /dev/md/RD6 metadata=1.2 UUID={UUID} name=younus:RD6
    spares=1
```

Comment: run `mdadm -E /dev/sd*` Make sure you get output for all devices. you might be able to assembly by giving each device (in correct order) with a `missing` in the correct place.

Comment: So, I tried ```mdadm --assemble /dev/md127 --force /dev/sd[a-j]```
But it gives me ```mdadm: /dev/sda is busy - skipping``` for every drive.

Comment: Assembly on all devices is NOT a good idea, you need to have the order correct. That is why I requested -E output --examine

Comment: Here "busy" means a device is already detected and claimed as a component of the array, while you tried to add it again. // Show us a real examine output for each array component (this will actually read MD superblocks from them and present in a human-readable form).

Comment: @NiKiZe here is the output.
http://ix.io/3DbM

Comment: What a mess. It lists everything as a spare.

Comment: Did you checked the health of all disks in question? I don't care with the one which is not the array member, but check at least SMART of all 8 other devices. If you notice any errors or problems like relocation events, relocated, unreadable sectors, and so on, don't proceed with this set of drives. I started writing an answer and realized if some device is faulty you'll likely destroy all the data if you attempt to assemble an array.

Comment: Yes, previously 3 of my drive has SMART error and the last one has SMART error now, so total 4. They were ok when I added them. But the error occurred when the array was reshaping. I thought that it wasn't a big deal because all of them were working fine.